# BigQuery - Max Partiton Date for a Custom Partitioned Table

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a metadata operation that can give me the max partitioned date/timestamp in use (for custom partitioned table not Ingest partitioning), such that I do not need to scan a whole table using MAX function?  Or some other clever SQL way?  Our source table is very large, and it gets a fresh snapshot of data *most* days - but then that data is generally for current_date()-1...but all in all I cant rely on much except for a query to tell me the max partition in use that doesnt cost the earth for a large table?  thought?

`SELECT MAX(custom_partition_field) FROM Y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#legacySQL
SELECT MAX(partition_id)
FROM [project:dataset.your_table$__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__]
```

It is documented at [Listing partitions in partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions#listing_partitions_in_partitioned_tables)

Comment: Thanks Mikhail - I think I was caught up in using StandardSQL I forgot about Legacy as an option - appreciated as always.

Comment: seems I cant schedule a legacy query, and I cant have a standardSQL based view consume a legacySql based view.  Hmmm...thoughts on options?

Comment: might be worthy of a new question (or feature request)