# BigQuery: Max Date for Time Partition on Custom Date Column

Tags: google-bigquery

I am currently working on the Optimization of a huge table in Google's BigQuery. The tables has approximately 19 billions records resulting in a total size of 5.2 TB. In order to experiment on performance with regards to clustering and time partitioning, I duplicated the table with a Time Partitioning on a custom DATE `MyDate` column which is frequently used in queries.
When performing a query with a `WHERE` clause (for instance, `WHERE(MyDate) = "2022-08-08"`) on the time partitioned table, the query is quicker and only reads around 20 GB compared to the 5.2 TB consumed by the table without partition. So far, so good.

My issue, however, arises when applying an aggregated function, i.e. in my case a `MAX(MyDate)`: the query on the partitioned and the non-partitioned tables read the same amount of data and execute in roughly the same time. However, I would have expected the query on the partitioned table to be way quicker as it only needs to scan a single partition.

There seem to be workarounds by fetching the dataset's metadata (information schema) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048018/bigquery-max-partiton-date-for-a-custom-partitioned-table). However, I would like to avoid solutions like this as it adds complexity to our queries.

Are there a more elegant ways to get the `MAX` of a time-partitioned BigQuery table based on a custom column without scanning the whole table or fetching metadata from the information schema?

Comment: "My issue, however, arises when applying an aggregated function" - to make sure I understand, you're saying that `SELECT MAX(MyDate) FROM table WHERE MyDate = "2022-08-08"` is scanning the same size as  `SELECT MAX(MyDate) FROM table`?
If what you mean is that  `SELECT MAX(MyDate) FROM table` is scanning all 19B rows, then that's normal: it has to scan the whole column to know what the MAX is. However, you could try doing something like `SELECT MAX(MyDate) FROM table WHERE MyDate > '2022-08-01'` (replacing 2022-08-01 by some date you know is earlier than the max date)

Comment: I get that you don’t want to make use of the workaround you are mentioning, but my recommendation is that you follow it since it’s the one that is better implemented on the issue you have